# I am using PostgreSQL with GraphQL when I try to delete any company that has relation with other tables. it shows GraphQL error:

Tags: postgresql, graphql, apollo-server, prisma, prisma-graphql

**tables schema**

```
type Company {
  id: ID! @unique
  name: String!
  users: [CompanyUser!]! @relation(name: "CompanyUserToCompany")
  areas: [Area!]! @relation(name: "Company_areas")
  positions: [Position!]! @relation(name: "Company_positions", onDelete: CASCADE)

}

type Position {
  id: ID! @unique
  name: String!
  users: [CompanyUser!]! @relation(name: "Position_company_user")
  company: Company! @relation(name: "Position_company", onDelete: CASCADE)

}
```

**Shows this GraphQL Error**

Error: GraphQL error: The change you are trying to make would violate the required relation 'Position_company' between Company and Position

Answer (score 0):

**If you're using prisma2, I guess my answer could help you.**

- Do not delete a item by Company.
  ( EX : `prisma.company.delete({where: ~ })` )
- Delete a item by Position.
  ( Ex. `prisma.position.delete({where:{company:{id:companyId}}})` )
- If it doesn't work and okay to change field attribute, make company field nullable( not required ). Then, delete Company first and delete Position( cuz I guess you want cascade, right? )

Don't forget to use await!

I solved this problem in this way. But I'm not sure for case in `onDelete:CASCADE`.
I reaaaally hope prisma2 release cascade soon..!